# How to display image URL path stored in modgodb in the front end using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have successfully stored the image path of the pictures uploaded. They look like this `http://localhost/public/Images/okro.jpg` but I don't know how to get them from the database and display them on the frontend.

Is there a way where I can get all the image path and display them on the frontend?

I use Express framework and Ejs as my view engine.

**EDIT**

The server.js code as requested.

```
var express = require("express"); 
var app = express (); 
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000; 
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var schema = mongoose.Schema; 
var passport = require('passport'); 
var expressValidator = require('express-validator'); 
var flash = require('connect-flash');  
var session = require('express-session'); 
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var configDB = require('./config/db.js');
var multer = require('multer'); 
var crypt  = require('crypto'); 
var static = require('express-static'); 
//var upload = multer({ dest: 'public/Images/' })



//connect to mlab database
mongoose.connect(configDB.url); 




// log every request to the console
app.use(morgan('combined')); 

//read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(cookieParser());

// get information from html forms
app.use(bodyParser()); 

//required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch' }));

app.use(passport.initialize());

// persistent login sessions
app.use(passport.session()); 

//connect-flash for displaying messages. 
app.use(flash()); 



// load our routes.  
require('./config/router.js')(app, passport); 


require('./config/passport.js')(passport); 


require('./config/upload.js')(app, crypt); 


//upload meme 
//require ('./config/upload.js'); 

// set up ejs for templating
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');     
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 
app.use(static(__dirname));

app.use(static(__dirname + 'Images'));


//app.use(static(__dirname + '/public'));

//app.use(static('/public'))

//app.use('public/Images', express.static('public'))

//app.use(express.directory(__dirname + '/public'));

//setting up multer
//app.use(multer()); 


//launch the app

app.listen(port); 

console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

[image: structure of my database]

Comment: You need not store `http://localhost/` in the URL.

Comment: What's the best way?

Comment: can you share your server.js code?

Comment: @RahulSharma I have updated the question to include the server.js code. Thanks

Comment: your server is running on 5000, not 80. uncomment this //app.use(static(__dirname + '/public'));

Comment: @RahulSharma Done that. How do I get the results from the database and display them on the frontend?

Comment: first check images are coming or not localhost:5000/<image path>

Comment: Done that. How do I query them to display them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `Images` as the static folder. So you would have just the name of the picture in your mongoDB. 
Eg:

```
"meme": {
  "imgs": "meme.jpg"
}
```

In your route:

```
app.get('/', function (req, result) {
  const query = Meme.findOne({});
  query.select('meme');
  query.exec(function (err, meme) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    result.render('/index', {
      path: meme.meme.imgs
    });
  }
}
```

In .ejs file, you would use:

```
<img src=<%= path %> alt="image">
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. What If I want to display all the images?

Comment: You would use `find{}` on server side and `for` loop in ejs over paths